# Jquery UI Datepicker onSelect and onInput events

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have 2 datepickers in my form, one used for a "pick-up" date and one used for a "drop-off" date.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datepicker_dropoff').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" 
    });

    $("#datepicker_pickup").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", 
        minDate:  0,
        onSelect: function(date){            
            var date1 =   $('#datepicker_pickup').datepicker('getDate');           
            var date = new Date( Date.parse( date1 ) ); 
            date.setDate( date.getDate() + 0 );        
            var newDate = date.toDateString(); 
            newDate = new Date( Date.parse( newDate ) );                      
            $('#datepicker_dropoff').datepicker("option","minDate",newDate);            
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see it is set that the dropoff date cannot be before the pickup date, and it's been done of course on purpose.

My problem is that in this format, the datepickers DO NOT keep the value and if I click on the form's Submit button, it keeps telling me that the datepicker fields need to be filled in, even though there's a value in each field. IF I manualyy just delete something in the field and then just add it again, it then works and no field prompt appears.
I think it has to do something with adding events ( which the datepicker is missing by default ? )

Can someone please help me out and append this to the code ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at DateRangePIcker - http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: how is the validation happening on submit? can you post that code too?

Comment: See, the thing is I use another script called CIVEM (https://github.com/javanto/civem.js/downloads ) to translate the field pop-ups. And that one kinda conflicts with the datepicker. Before I modified the datepickers so that the dropoff date cannot be before the pickup date, the developer helped me by adding an onSelect and onInput event but in this case it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Its working fine with the above code.can you please provide code where you are getting error.

Comment: Better you can explain this in Jsfiddle. It would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: @Luc why do you have so much conversions inside of `onSelect`? It seems they are quite useless. You can simply start with `var date = $('#datepicker_pickup').datepicker('getDate');`, remove `date` argument and finish with setting minDate option.

Comment: I had a similiar problem last week on my end here and I solved it, but before I give a solution could you provide a fiddle, I might be able to help you out here.

Answer (score 1):

Ooooldish question but my answer:

So I prefer to change my min/max dates in the `.change(function() { })`. That way the min/max date only get changed if the dates are actually changed.

Assuming HTML:

```
<input type='text' id='datepicker_pickup'>
    to
<input type='text' id='datepicker_dropoff'>
```

And jquery and jqueryui 1.10.2 using this javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker_dropoff').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
    }).change(function() {
        var date1 =   $('#datepicker_pickup').datepicker('getDate');
        $('#datepicker_pickup').datepicker('option','maxDate',date1);
    });

    $("#datepicker_pickup").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
        ,minDate: 0
    }).change(function() {
        var date1 =   $('#datepicker_pickup').datepicker('getDate');
        $('#datepicker_dropoff').datepicker('option','minDate',date1);
    });
});
```

[here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1h2dd92p/)